# Roll back project using Git (Force pull?)

Tags: git, github, git-branch

what I've done is I have a project in my work space and on GitHub. I experimented with changing some code, and to undo those changes will take forever by hand. What I want to do is grab the branch using Git and force it to replace my work space branch. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why don't you just use `git revert`?

Comment: `git revert` will create a commit that undoes (reverts) another commit, it's probably not what OP wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll use [`git reset --hard`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)

So if you're working on master then the remote branch is origin/master, simply

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```